# JSONB fields and string keys

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've a JSONB column with the following content:

{"ibd": true, "participant_id": "P016", "sample_participant_id": "B1"}

If I query the value without the double quotation mark I get an error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json LINE 1: ...ERE
>   sample_metadata.metadata->'sample_participant_id' = 'B1'

for:

```
WHERE sample_metadata.metadata->'sample_participant_id' = 'B1'
```

But for

```
WHERE sample_metadata.metadata->'sample_participant_id' = '"B1"'
```

It works as expected. What I don't understand is why I need the double quotation mark. are they an actual value?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->` operator on a `jsonb` returns `jsonb`, so you can't compare a json with a string literal(`'B1'`) or `text` type.

```
WHERE sample_metadata.metadata->'sample_participant_id' = '"B1"'
```

works because element `"B1"`  can be implicitly cast to `jsonb` for comparison

You should rather be using the `->>` operator for your comparison. It returns `text`

```
WHERE metadata->>'sample_participant_id' = 'B1'
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=14600b74b0615ced885b4cbd979c5f91)